# Facebook Share button won't display in Chrome

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome, share

I'm buidling a rails app and I'm having trouble getting the Facebook Share button to display in Chrome or Firefox.  It shows up fine in IE and Safari. The Like and Login buttons work fine in all browsers.  I've searched the web, but can't find anything helpful.

On each page I have

```
<!-- Facebook SDK -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.onload = function()
{
  // Additional JS functions here
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//localhost:3000/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

  (function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }(document));

}
```

On the page I want the Share button to appear, I have

```
<fb:share-button type="button_count"></fb:share-button>
```

Per Adam's suggestion I created an HTML file.  THe login button appears but the share button doesn't

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<HEAD>
   <TITLE>Untitled HTML Document</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY BGCOLOR="white">
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script>

  (function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=MY_APP_ID"; // APP ID
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>
FB
<fb:share-button type="box_count"></fb:share-button> <br>
<div class="fb-login-button" data-width="200"></div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like the problem was with me using localhost as my url.  I changed my /etc/hosts file so that fakeurl.com points to 127.0.0.1 and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Add `xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#"` to your `<HTML>` tag:

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

Change your `<script>`

```
(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=YOUR_APP_ID"; // APP ID
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KVfWq/)

Comment: It still won't display in Chrome or Firefox

Comment: I pasted my portion of the ccode in that handles this in jsfiddle.net and the button displays fine.  I wonder if it's  browser setting or some other piece of code

Comment: Try creating an HTML file for Test to see if there's another tag effects it

Comment: I didn't mention that this is a RoR app on Linux.  I created a simple page in Windows and the share button didn't appear but the login button did.  See edited post above